# iAd+In App purchase app -download new binary

Tags: ios4, binary, in-app-purchase, iad

I am creating an in app purchase application with iAds. I have already submitted the same application (without iAd and inAPP purchase) as a paid application and it is available on apple store. When my free application will be ready and available in apple store then I will have two binaries- one for free app and one for paid app.

Once a user make a payment by in app purchase then I want to unlock all items and remove iAds. In other words, after payment it should be exactly like the paid application. Instead of disabling iAds and unlocking locked items by code, I want that users download paid application  after payment which should replace their free application. Is it possible to do that? How do you do that?

Do I need to submit two binaries? Can you give me the sample code by which a new download will start after payment and free application will be replaced by the paid application?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do such a thing. You have two solutions :

- Post a second binary which will be free with in app purchase :

  - Not a good idea, since you will have two versions to maintain
- Update the actual binary to mark the current user as a paid user and then a second update will bring iAds with in-app and application will be free.

  - New users will have iAds and in-app enabled
  - Old users will have no ads, and won't have to pay again since you have saved their old state.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent logic!  Too bad the original person did not mark this as answer.

Comment: Brilliant, but what about old users who didn't launch the app between the first update and the second?

Comment: @suprandr indeed you are stuck with them. Unless you have a user account you cannot do a thing. You can still try to see which CoreData model version your user have (if you are using CoreData).